# Print out the circular linked list in C++?

Tags: c++, pointers, linked-list, circular-list

I want to print out a circular linked list. How would you print them out?

This one is for regular linked list. And if I implement this for circular list, it loops for ever. Any idea to restrict and print out just one circle?

```
struct node* curr_node_1 = head;
while ( curr_node_1 != nullptr )
{
    cout << curr_node_1->p_data << ", ";
    curr_node_1 = curr_node_1->p_next;
}
```

And my node struct is following

```
 struct node
 {
    int            p_data;
    struct node*   p_next;

    node(node* head, int data)
    {
        p_next = head;
        p_data = data;
    }

    explicit node(int data)
    {
        p_next = nullptr;
        p_data = data;
    }
 };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just replace the column ending condition with `head` instead of `nullptr` and take care that the loop is run through at all:

```
struct node* curr_node_1 = head;
if(curr_node_1 != nullptr)
{
    do
    {
        cout << curr_node_1->p_data << ", ";
        curr_node_1 = curr_node_1->p_next;
    } while ( curr_node_1 != head );
}
```

Comment: How can you access the list then at all?

Comment: Have you sued the code exactly as I put it in? Especially, is the value that `head` points to the first entry, and thus the one that the last entry in the list points to? Maybe it is time to run through this in a debugger to see why the last entry is not pointing to the same value as `head`.

Comment: Oh it works, I was getting infinite loop trying other things. Thanks